# “File name too long” while deleting directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I am deleting a directory which has almost 600 nested directories inside it using `rm -rf <directory name>` . This command is showing error : File name too long.

I tried `find <path to directory> -type d -delete` but this shows directory not empty error.

How to delete such directory?

Answer (score 0):

There is most definitly at least one softlink or a mountpoint involved - else the kernel would not have allowed creation of the files.

- If it is a link: delete the files from the original path.
- If it is a mountpoint: mount to a shorter path

You can also do it by hand: `cd` into a "halfway" directory, then `rm -rf *`, then step back and repeat.